# How to achieve this layout? Table titles are not aligned with the content also the content of each row is not vertically aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve this layout:

[image: picture of desired output]

- Where the type column at left that occupies much more width than the other 2 items at the right, this is because the type and description can be large.
- Also, the type and description of each item should be vertically aligned with the quantity select menu and the subtotal content.

I'm using bootstrap, but I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to achieve this layout using the table component. I don’t know if using the table component for this layout is the more correct approach or panel or some other thing.

The layout that I'm getting is this:https://jsfiddle.net/bcvm3ap2/, but the table titles are not aligned with the content also the content of each row is not vertically aligned.

Do you know how fix? And also if the table is a correct approach for this layout?

html:

```
<div class="row no-gutters bg-white">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 px-4 pb-4">
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm border">
      <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <th scope="col" class="mr-auto">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="">
            <span class="text-heading-blue font-weight-semi-bold">Type1</span>
            <small class="font-weight-light d-block">Description</small>
          </td>
          <td><select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option selected class="selected">0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="">
            <span class="text-heading-blue font-weight-semi-bold">Type2</span>
            <small class="font-weight-light d-block">Description</small>
          </td>
          <td><select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option selected class="selected">2</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

With panels is also not working: https://jsfiddle.net/jdpr21qw/1/ The titles are not aligned with the content.

Comment: For a beginner, I'm not sure I would jump into bootstrap 4, bootstrap 3 is much simpler to start with imho - this is what's causing you problems `<tr class="d-flex justify-content-between">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will give you the layout what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row no-gutters bg-white">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 px-4 pb-4">
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered">
      <thead class='text-center'>
        <tr class="text-center ">
          <th scope="col" class="mr-auto">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr >
          <td class="">
            <span class="text-heading-blue font-weight-semi-bold">Type1</span>
            <br/><small class="font-weight-light d-block">Description</small>
          </td>
          <td><select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option selected class="selected">0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="">
            <span class="text-heading-blue font-weight-semi-bold">Type2</span>
            <br/><small class="font-weight-light d-block">Description</small>
          </td>
          <td><select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option selected class="selected">2</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with Darren Sweeney. Bootstrap 3 isn't simpler. Bootstrap 4 is.

As far as the question goes: 
Yes, the table isn't the correct approach for this layout because the HTML table in Bootstrap doesn't give you much control. Tables are really only meant for displaying tabular data. When you want a column to be a particular width, then using tables becomes the wrong approach.

Bootstrap simply isn't designed to create HTML tables where you can specify the width of a particular column. Bootstrap can help you style the overall look of HTML tables a bit but as soon as you want to specify the width of a particular column... Well, you could specify the width in the HTML but that would be plain HTML and non-responsive i.e. nothing to do with Bootstrap.

And by the way, if you replace 
`<tr class="d-flex justify-content-between">` 
with 
`<tr>`
your table is gonna look just fine. Except, the first column isn't gonna be wider than the others. UNLESS, of course, you add more content in the first column: 
[image]